# Is there a way to have a database with stored procedures as a Visual Studio 2010 project?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

How can I add a storedprocedure to my Visual Studio 2010 solution?

I require a storedprocedure to demo some sample code in Visual Studio. I do not want the user 
to have to setup a database.

I've had a quick look at the Visual Studio 2010 SQL Server Database Project but I'm not sure it's the right direction, is it?

1 table and a couple of stored procedures would suffice right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see comment above 
SQL Server Database File is what I was looking for, msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk2tbfb5.aspx